# Collection result are wrong

Tags: magento-enterprise, database, mysql, collection

I have collection, so if I used `$collection->getSelect()` to view the query and run directly in mysql it give me right result but id I used to see total result using `$collection->count()` then it is not giving the right result.

So count used the `load()` function because of that my gird view do not have filter result which should be.

Can any one help me around it what is happening here?

Even I call the select query after the loading (`$collection->load()`) the collection, still query is right but collection result are wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I got the answer for this, collection was already loaded before I added the filter. This was happening through an event. SO if someone facing same issue then check collection should not loaded before filter.